# Does MS Access Runtime 2010 works well on system with previous version of Access/Office installed?

Tags: ms-access, runtime, ms-office, backwards-compatibility

I'm developing an application using MS Access 2010 that would be deployed using Access Runtime 2010 on target PC.

Is there any issues running Access Runtime 2010 on systems with previous version of Access/ Office installed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464282/viewing-accdb-with-access-2010-runtime-when-access-2007-is-installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, all the compatibility issues you have with the full edition or when you've install multiple editions of the access and office on a computer remain the same when you attempt to use the runtime system.

In other words to translate this and make it really simple:

the compatibility of the access runtime extends into that of having exactly the same problems you'll have if you attempt to install and use the full edition of access on a computer.  Now I suppose you could be happy to hear that the compatibility is very high, but the sad part is that compatibility also extends into exactly the same problems existing.

What this means is the hijack extension issues and several other issues will exist if you attempt to install and run multiple versions of access on the same computer.  I stress again this extends into using the runtime which should not be considered any different than installing the full addition of access on the target computer. The problems and challenges of installing multiple versions of access does not in any way shape or form change when you install the runtime edition. (so consider the question and answers in regards to multiple editions of access totally irrelevant as to the full edition being installed, or the runtime edition being installed, their problems are exactly the same because their exactly compatible in this area of regards.

There is a way to work around this limitation, and that is to consider adoption and using a commercial installer for access, there's some companies that build scripts and installers that eliminate the above problems, one such company which I recommend is here.

www.sagekey.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've actually explored the sagekey solution and it fitted my needs.